# Anaconda menu failed

Tags: menu

I tried downloading/installing Versions 3.4, then 3.6 of Anaconda on Windows 10. Each time. I got an error message that the Anaconda menu filed to load. 
I did a re-try, then even tried to IGNORE, but then I got another message that the directories had failed to load. Are these versions meant for Windows 10?

Thanks - Steve

Answer (score 0):

This has come up quite a bit. It should be fixed in Anaconda4.3.1. It often happens when installing to all user areas and if you have spaces or unicode characters in the username. It is best to install to your user directory. Even though it gives an error Anaconda is still installed, it just didn't make the Start Menu items. You can install them yourself:

```
conda install -f console_shortcut ipython ipython-qtconsole anaconda-navigator spyder jupyter
```